# I have used FlatList and I want to get the rowId in the function which has been used to render items of list, how can I get that?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have used this `FlatList`, where I have called `renderRow` function in which I have written code to render list Items, How can I get the `rowId` for each row `renderer` in `renderRow` method?

```
<List containerStyle={{borderTopWidth:0 , borderBottomWidth:0}}>
        <FlatList data={this.state.horseList}
        renderItem={(item) => this.renderRow(item)}
        _keyExtractor ={item => item.id} 
        onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={1}
        ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
        onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
        />
    </List>
```

Answer (score 26):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can access the index of each row in this way:

```
   <FlatList data={this.state.horseList}
     ...
     renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderRow(item, index)}
     ...
   />
```

Comment: Had the same issue. Your answer solved the issue. Thanks Vahid.

Comment: But how about lambda inside of the render, it is not a good idea for the performance

Comment: It's just a sample code, performance is not guaranteed. You can use `useCallback` to avoid performance issues.